# no preflight request despite request mode 'cors'

Tags: http, web, webpack, browser, cors

my app uses scripts (in this particular example `webpack`) to load certain resources (not relevant for this matter), the request headers looks like below:

```
GET /b245bc85ddeedb27a549.woff2 HTTP/2
Host: anonymized.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0
Accept: application/font-woff2;q=1.0,application/font-woff;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en,pl;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: identity
Origin: https://www.anonymized.de
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://www.anonymized.de/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: font
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-GPC: 1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
TE: trailers
```

the script which is initializing the request is coming from the `anonymized.com` domain and is executed on the `https://www.anonymized.de/` url

each time the resource is requested I'm getting following error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://anonymized.com/b245bc85ddeedb27a549.woff2. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.
```

but the thing is that there is NO preflight (the `OPTIONS` request) being done before the request, lol

so my question is how to make the browser to do the preflight (or what is needed to make the error disappear because as you see I'm not sending any special headers)

Comment: Not all cross-origin requests give rise to a preflight request (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests), and the key to fixing the CORS error you observe is not to force the browser to issue a preflight request. Web-font resource require CORS to be configured if they're to be consumed on a different Web origin. Do you control the server that's running on `anonymized.de`? If so, you can configure it for CORS. If not, you're out of luck.

Comment: @jub0bs no, I do not, but I have contact to the person who do, what do they need to do?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#what_requests_use_cors and https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-fetching-requirements